# lwuit app would not run on blackberry jde

Tags: lwuit, blackberry-simulator, jde

I built a j2me app using sun's lwuit , the application runs fine on my Oracle sdk simulator,but when I run this same app on blackberry jde I get this error

```
Error preverifying class com.sun.lwuit.animations.Transition3D
VERIFIER ERROR com/sun/lwuit/animations/Transition3D.initTransition()V:

Cannot find class javax/microedition/m3g/Node
C:\Users\Guest\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JTMobile\nbproject\build-impl.xml:436:   Preverification failed with error code 1.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 38 seconds)
```

then I ignore this error and run the application again, it runs fine,
but when I launch the application I get this error

```
App Error 104, Uncaught Illegal argument then on the error confirmation box
Uncaught Exception ,Midlet jtMobile.Midlet not Found exception
```

I have checked all over the internet ,and it seems lwuit_midp.jar library isn't supported by blackberry , is there a way to run this app or configure the project so as to write lwuit j2me apps to run on blackberry, I some what prefer native lwuit and j2me Midlets to writing UIApplication from RIM, im using the latest lwuit 1_5, and blackberry OS 7.1/CLDC 1.1 MIDP 2.0 ,please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look on this [thread](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/wsnyder6/archive/2008/07/success_lwuit_o.html), where you can find that if you remove the problematic classes from you lwuit file, you can get it working. Open the .jar file and delete this files.

Instead of this, I recommend you to use [CodenameOne](http://www.codenameone.com/), which is a powerful tool which let us to develop with one lwuit based code, to a lot of platforms (Nokia, BB, Android, iOS) .

Comment: i actually removed the Transition3d class in animation package and the M3g classes, it worked but it show this error on start-up and launches the app

Answer (score 1):

Nokia work with [MIDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Information_Device_Profile).

Blackbery work with another library - RIM.

if You want to run the same application on Blackbeery you need to do like this:

```
    public class XXXXXXXtMIDlet extends
        //#ifdef RIM
        net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication
        //#else
//#         javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet
        //#endif
```

In addtional , where the implemntion is specific to Blackberry you need to use ifdef RIM statment.

Comment: thanks blay for the response, no, i actually wish to run a lwuit midlet application on blackberry without using RIM's api or UIApplication, isnt there a way to port a lwuit midlet application into blackberry?

Comment: It's no the same. Midlet and Rim are run with device Os. lwuit is powerful tool that take care on UI. i worked with lwuit in blackbary project.